# Where to plug in the power switch on a HP proliant ml330 g6 systemboard?

Tags: hardware, hp, hp-proliant, cable, system-building

The cable of the Powerswitch in the case needs 2 Pins, but there are 20 Pins at the front panel connector of the Mainbaord. Where I have to plug in this Cable?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you have the correct spare part, `519739-001` [Power Button/LED Assembly](http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c02202427)?

It should have only one connector, referred in the manual like this:

> 6. Connect the power button/LED assembly cable to the system board.

On the [HPE ProLiant ML330 G6 Server - Remove/Replace Videos](https://sml-csr.ext.hpe.com/results.htm?SID=3948598&MEID=B3AA6781-9C7E-4074-BB21-CC8112763B6E) you can see this cable on the video *Power button/led assembly* (0:21-), and it is a single 20-pin cable for the whole connector:

[image]

Therefore, the *HP ProLiant ML330 G6 Server Maintenance and Service Guide* doesn't even have any guidance for the connector pinout, as it doesn't assume you would be connecting individual 2-pin cables.

The only 2-pin (red/black) cable involved should be the *temperature sensor*. If it's not connected for some reason, there's also a video for that on the same [media library page](https://sml-csr.ext.hpe.com/results.htm?SID=3948598&MEID=B3AA6781-9C7E-4074-BB21-CC8112763B6E). It seems to belong to the lowest 2 pins on the *"reserved"* (27) connector right above the *fan 3 connector* (26).

[image]